# APNS closing connection after first write

Tags: go, apple-push-notifications

After my first write to the socket, APNS closes the connection! The first notification sends perfectly fine, but the second one fails because of EOF.

I've attached a small snippet of my code for sending a notification. Let me know if I should include more. Thanks for the help!

```
func (notificationService *NotificationService) Send(deviceToken []byte, payload *Payload, expiration time.Time, priority int) (uint32, error) {
    apnsBinary, err := createApnsBinary(deviceToken, payload, notificationIdentifier, expiration, priority)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    _, err = notificationService.connection.Write(apnsBinary)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    responseBytes := make([]byte, 6, 6)
    bytesRead, err := notificationService.connection.Read(responseBytes)
    if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        return 0, err
    } else if bytesRead > 0 {
        errorResponseInHex := hex.EncodeToString(responseBytes[:bytesRead])
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("Received bad response %s", errorResponseInHex)
    }

    if err == io.EOF {
        fmt.Println("BOO NOT AGAIN!!")
    }

    return notificationIdentifier, nil
}
```

Comment: Are you certain the first (or second) message is formatted correctly ? If it isn't, the receiver might close the connection-

Comment: That was my first suspicion, however the permutation of the messages doesn't seem to make a difference :/

Comment: I take that back! The first message is causing the EOF! However it's still being delivered?...

Comment: I think you know better than anyone here whether your message is delivered or not. And what do you mean by "delivered" ? The APNS read your message, successfully processed it, and you can observe the effect of this message elsewhere ?

Comment: Yep, I see the notification appear on my phone

Answer (score 0):

If the first message was delivered successfully and the second failed, it is more likely the connection was closed due to a problem in the second message. The most likely problem would be an invalid device token (which could happen if you use a development token when pushing to the production APNS env, or vice versa).

Try to send only the second message, and see if it works. If not, the problem is definitely in that message.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It doesn't seem to matter what order I send the messages in. Even sending the same message twice causes the problem.

Comment: The first message is definitely being received by the client. I'm using the dev token with the sandbox APNS